# Can I integrate Outlook-Office 365 and an on-premise SP 2013 installation?

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-on-prem

We have an on-premise installation of SP 2013 with no Exchange server, just an active directory for user administration.  We purchased an Office 365 account to see if we could use it for email / calendaring.  I have a sharepoint calendar that I tried adding an exchange calendar over it.  I provide the `outlook.office365.com` web access url and the Exchange url `outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx`.  But how would I store credentials for the O365 account?  Obviously it is using different credentials than our AD.  If I pull up the Exchange URL in a browser and provide my credentials that I received from I Microsoft, I can view the service.  But how can I store it in Sharepoint so people can add items to the calendar?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supported if you have the correct [service upgrade](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/am-i-using-office-365-after-the-service-upgrade-HA103982331.aspx?redir=0):

> The URL of Exchange Online Web Service is a URL like
>
> `"https://" + "Server name" + "/EWS/Exchange.amsx"`
>
> for example, `https://pod51024.outlook.com/ews/exchange.amsx`.
>
> You can refer to the steps below to find the URL of exchange web service in your mailbox.
>
> - Logon to your e-mail account using Outlook Web App (OWA).
> - Click Options > See All Options > Account > My Account > Settings for POP, IMAP, and SMTP access.
> - In the list of entries, locate the server name. And the URL of exchange web service for your mailbox is the URL: `"https://" + "Server name" + "/EWS/Exchange.amsx"`.
>     The Outlook Web Access Url is: `"https://" + "Server name" + "/OWA”`.

Reference: [SharePoint online calendar overlay with exchange online user](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/152627.aspx?pageindex=1)

I havn't tried this myself, but I think it would work on an On Premise SharePoint installation as well, provided that you have ADFS correctly set up with all four SSL cerificates. Good Luck!

Comment: I understand the trust between environments, but how does mapping work between my AD of users and another (Office 365) set of users?  Where does it occur that says this user from this domain should be able to see that user's email in Office 365?

Comment: @user23915 Have your users sign in with the Active Directory account instead of the Office 365 account should solve the problem. You shouldn't have to use the O365 accounts, as I understand it.